# Can't minify ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I tried `cordova-uglify` ([link](https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-uglify)) to minify a Ionic1 project, after I run

```
ionic cordova build --release
```

I see my js source code in `www` folder of `app-release-unsigned.apk`.. is not minified at all.

`ionic info` prints:

```
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying
       .\bower.json.

cli packages: (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
    Gulp CLI              : not installed globally

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 7
```

Edit: I noticed when I run `ionic cordova build --release` I get those errors:

```
An error ocurred while reading directories:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\js'
An error ocurred while reading directories:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\css'
An error ocurred while reading directories:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\img'
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\nodejs\myproject\hooks\after_prepare\uglify.js C:\nodejs\myproject

processFiles err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\js'
processFiles err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\css'
processFiles err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\img'
processFiles err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\build'
```

**I do not have a `.\platforms\android\assets\www` folder**

@Antonis Those are the steps I tried:

- I deleted node_modules and reinstalled `npm install`
- I tried `npm rebuild node-sass --force`
- remove and re-add android platform `ionic cordova build --release`
- still get the errors `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir C:\nodejs\myproject\platforms\android\assets\www\js [...]`

**How can I generate that `assets` folder?**
I see there is an **assets** folder in `.\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets` but the module **ionic-minify** search for `.\platforms\android\assets`

Comment: Try to deleting your node_modules and run npm install again. If it does not work try: npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: @Antonis I edited the question with your suggestions

Comment: Are you in the root of your project folder when you run the commands?

Comment: yes I'm in the root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed I have an assets folder in `platforms\android\app\src\main\assets` so I edited  `.\hooks\after_prepare\uglify.js`  and
`.\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js`   to match that path. It looks like it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this minify node module for your ionic project.

```
https://github.com/Jiansen/ionic-minify
```

Comment: I see `ionic-minify.js` has been created in `hooks\after_prepare`, but still doesn't work, the code is not minified.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify `hooks/uglify-config.json`.  By default, there is an entry that reads:

```
"foldersToProcess": [
    "platforms/browser/www"
],
```

Change it to the empty string:

```
"foldersToProcess": [
    ""
],
```